# Change Hard Drive Mounted Location Debian

Tags: debian, hard-drive, mount

I just realized my hard drive is mounted to the wrong directory, how many I change the directory in which it is mounted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the "/etc/fstab"file (as root). The syntax is:

```
/your/device    /dir/where/mounted    <type>    <opts>   <dump/pass>
```

You just need to fix the "/dir/where/mounted", and reboot.

Or you can do it manually (after reboot, fstab will be read, and mounted 'wrongly' again):

```
umount /your/wrong/dir
mount /dev/yourdiskXY /your/right/dir
```